# AWS DynamoDB: "Error: Missing region in config" - even with 'config.region' returning 'eu-west-1'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

While following the AWS docs for setting up DynamoDB in my front end project, with settings taken from the docs the API throws:

```
Error: Missing region in config
    at constructor.<anonymous> (aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:42)
    at constructor.callListeners (aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:44)
    at i (aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:44)
    at aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:42
    at t (aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:41)
    at constructor.getCredentials (aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:41)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:42)
    at constructor.callListeners (aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:44)
    at constructor.emit (aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:44)
    at constructor.emitEvent (aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:43)
```

My settings:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId:'eu-west-1_XXXXXX'});
  var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
    credentials: myCredentials, region: 'eu-west-1',
  });

  console.log(myConfig.region); //logs 'eu-west-1'

  var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});    
  dynamodb.listTables({Limit: 10}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Table names are ", data.TableNames);
    }
  });
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you’re newing up AWS.config.

Change the line

```
var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
    credentials: myCredentials, region: 'eu-west-1',
  });
```

to

```
AWS.config.update({
        credentials: myCredentials, region: 'eu-west-1',
      }});
```

**Reference:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your help, if i try with the above, AWS now ironically throws: `Error: Missing credentials in config at constructor.s (aws-sdk-2.129.0.min.js:43)`. There may be some extra settings to be made in Cognito to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

For others hitting the same issue, where the docs mention:

> If you have not yet created one, **create an identity pool**...

and you got forwarded to the Amazon Cognito service, choose the **Manage Federal Identities** not the **Manage User Pools** option.